# Loading configurations Meta Data

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration

My application needs some meta data configuration to be loaded at server start up. Meta data are annotations and its **do-it-once-forget it-and-use** kind. So reading annotations and loading the MetaData objects involves lot of reflection hence I want to do it only once.

Is there any way other than using using Singletons ? I saw `@Singleton` EJBs which may serve the purpose. But I'm using EJB 3.0 hence that support is not available.

Do you see any other approach (efficient and simple) I can use for this purpose ?

**To be more clear** :

Using annotations on some classes we are building some configuration objects, that'll be used throughout the application. Hence reading the annotations and building the config objects has to be done only once.

Comment: I don't think there are enough details here to really be able to provide a helpful answer. You want to execute some logic when the server/application starts up - so write a hook into the startup routine to do this? In a webapp you could do this with a context listener, filter etc. Or is there more to the question than the *how*?

Comment: I think you might want to do some reading on the Singleton Design Pattern.  It would be fairly easy to create a class that only loads the properties once and could be referenced by the application.  If I understand you correctly, it sounds like that is what you should use rather than annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for the problem.

I have a `@PostConstruct` annotated method which reads all the configuration meta data and create the objects. And in the EJB deployment descriptor I configure the `initial-number of beans in pool` as 1 and also `maximum number of beans` as 1. Hence this would be a singleton and at the same time would be loaded on server startup.